# Fetch details of application from google play using package name?

Tags: android, google-play

Can anybody please tell me how to fetch all the details of android app including icon, screenshots and description from google play using its package name? If there is any api for this then please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play has no official API apart from the [documented Intents](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html) that can be used to launch the Google Play app to a specific page.

Other than that, there is an [unofficial API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) that can run some queries and return data, but can't do everything.

Comment: thanks raghav , so according to you there is no way to get all the details.

Comment: No official way, and any unofficial way that may exist could stop working at any moment

Comment: So what I have to do for this. Actually I have to make a replica of AppTo (android app) and this app is fetching all the details from the Google play, that’s y I asked this question.

Comment: They are most likely using a webserver to periodically scrape data like icons, descriptions, screenshots etc. of the Google Play website, and then sending this data to their app and displaying it.

Comment: @Raghav is someone serially down-voting you?

Comment: @Reno I don't think so. Only two downvotes, and not close enough to make me suspicious