# What it's the url of the googleplay screenshots?

Tags: android

I have the google play url for an android App.
How can I get the different screenshot of this App?

Comment: No definite URL scheme. Maybe there is an API for accessing the images?

Comment: ^ None that i know of.

Comment: Best bet would be to scrape the page for the image container and get the value of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an unofficial open-source API for the Android Market.
Check this out: https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Answer (score 2):

If you need to take screenshots of the application just run the application in eclipse, click DDMS then there is an option to capture screen as "screen capture". Try this..

You had better take screenshots of emulator. Some devices dont permit screen capture if the phone is not rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123841/fetch-details-of-application-from-google-play-using-package-name) there appears to be an unofficial API for this.
Please report back and tell us if it's working for you (or not).

Comment: Beat me for 19 seconds, hehe.

Comment: I hope you've spent these 19 seconds well :)