# Get app detail by package name from Play-store

Tags: android, google-play

I want to get app detail (currently `app category`) on play-store.

I searched and got [this library](https://github.com/ldrolez/android-market-api). But this is very old library and I think there should be Google official API to get play-store data for an package name. I visited [Google Api Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library), but i did not get any API named by play-store.

So some one tell me proper way to get app detail on play-store.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123841/fetch-details-of-application-from-google-play-using-package-name

Comment: That did not help me, i have mentioned google-api-market library in question.

Comment: `Google Play does not offer an official API to get app details `

Comment: That answer says to open play store page, how can that help me out?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-get-Android-application-details-from-Google-Play-Store-by-package-name

Comment: that was answered on Aug 25 '12, Its been 6 years so i thought there can be an API now.

Comment: i know the answer is old that's why i didn't close your question as duplicate and second thing that link if just for information

Comment: Did i shout! Not at all, and quora link can help me let me check it out.

Comment: Yes you can mark duplicate if that satisfy the user. I just wanted to know if there is new API launched for this purpose. That's user right to ask if he is not satisfied with old answer.

Comment: *`That's user right to ask if he is not satisfied with old answer`* have  u discussed this in that old answer about your doubt?  **i think NOT**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch details of application from google play using package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123841/fetch-details-of-application-from-google-play-using-package-name)

Comment: I have voted to close as a duplicate. I know you have said it is old. Even old answers get edited on stack overflow if the answer changes, instead of new questions. In this particular case, the answer hasn't changed, there is no official API. Out of interest, why do you want such an API?

Comment: I could not get a solution, finally i solved it out with an hack own. The library mentioned in answers are 6 years old, and not working at all now. I will post answer soon.